# Get active value from union-style enum in generic method

Tags: generics, enums, type-conversion, rust

I have code similar to the following:

```
enum Value {
    Bool(bool),
    Int(i32),
    Float(f32),
    Str(String),
}

fn get_value(key: &str) -> Value {
    // read value from file
    match key {
        "b" => Value::Bool(true),
        "i" => Value::Int(666),
        "f" => Value::Float(42.),
        "s" => Value::Str("".to_string()),
         _  => panic!("Key {} not found.", str),
    }
}

fn convert<T>(e: &Value) -> T {
    // what to put here?
}

fn query<T>(t: &str) -> T {
    // … validation etc.
    convert::<T>(&get_value(t))
}

fn main() {
    let i = query::<i32>("i");
}
```

I.e. I need to `query` some values from a text file. `query` takes a type parameter and a string key parameter. It then returns the value associated to that key in the text file (if the type parameter and the type of the value don't match, simply `panic!`). `Value` and `get_value` are from a library in the actual code.

However I'm facing a problem when trying to `convert` a `Value` instance to the type it holds. If I try to do it with a simple `match`, I get

> error: mismatched types:  expected `T`,
>       found `x`

where `x` is one of `bool`/`i32`/`f32`/`String`.

What is the right way to do this in Rust?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here there is a possible solution:

```
enum Value {
    Bool(bool),
    Int(i32),
    Float(f32),
    Str(String),
}

fn get_value(key: &str) -> Value {
    // read value from file
    match key {
        "b" => Value::Bool(true),
        "i" => Value::Int(666),
        "f" => Value::Float(42.),
        "s" => Value::Str("".to_string()),
         _  => panic!("Key {} not found.", key),
    }
}

trait ConversionTrait {
    type Output;

    fn convert(v: &Value) -> Option<Self::Output> {
        None
    }
}

impl ConversionTrait for i32 {
    type Output = i32;

    fn convert(v: &Value) -> Option<Self::Output> {
        match (*v) {
            Value::Int(x) => Some(x),
            _ => None
        }
    }
}

fn convert<T>(e: &Value) -> Option<T> where T : ConversionTrait<Output = T> {
    T::convert(e)
}


fn query<T>(t: &str) -> Option<T> where T : ConversionTrait<Output = T> {
    // … validation etc.
    convert::<T>(&get_value(t))
}

fn main() {
    let i = query::<i32>("i");
    // let j = query::<f32>("i"); ConversionTrait not implemented
    println!("{:?}", i);
}
```

First of all the `convert` and `query` methods could fail, so it's better they return an `Option` which can be `None` in case of failure.

Second, in Rust there is no generic specialization at the moment so a possible solution is to define a trait to do the conversion then implement the trait only for the types you want the conversion.
(with generic specialization you would implement different version of the convert function)

Each implementation of the `ConversionTrait` above should extract the proper value from the `Value` object and return it.
I implemented only the `i32` version for reference.

Comment: Ah, of course this makes sense. This basically creates a trait that parallels `FromStr`, but is tailored to the source type in question. Very nice!

Comment: Although, implementing the trait for `i32` and having an associated type for `i32` seems redundant — I think you don't want the associated type.

Answer (score 4):

[Andrea P's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32149409/3425536) was really helpful. I adapted it a little and also made a macro to avoid code duplication in the `impl Convert`s. Here's the result just in case anyone is interested:

```
trait Convert : Sized {
    fn convert(Value) -> Option<Self>;
}

macro_rules! impl_convert {
    ($t:ty, $id:ident) => (
        impl Convert for $t {
            fn convert(v: Value) -> Option<$t> {
                match v {
                    Value::$id(x) => Some(x),
                    _ => None,
                }
            }
        }
    )
}

impl_convert!(bool, Bool);
impl_convert!(i32, Int);
impl_convert!(f32, Float);
impl_convert!(String, Str);

fn query<T: Convert>(t: &str) -> T {
    // … validation etc.
    match T::convert(get_value(t)) {
        Some(x) => x,
        None => panic!("`{}` has an incorrect type", t),
    }
}
```

`Convert` inherits `Sized` to prevent:

> **warning**: the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type `Self`

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that you can't. Check out your function prototype:

```
fn convert<T>(e: &Value) -> T
```

This says that for any `T` that the *caller chooses*, the function has to return that. That would entail a very large number of possibilities, including every type ever created by any user of this code.

However, there's a *type* of solution for your problem. You just need to look at how the standard library implements [`str::parse`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse):

```
fn parse<F>(&self) -> Result<F, F::Err> 
    where F: FromStr
{
    FromStr::from_str(self)
}
```

[`FromStr`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html) is the real hero here, and many types implement it. Any type that implements `FromStr` can be used with `parse`.

I believe that you can use `FromStr` for your case, because your code doesn't make any sense. ^_^ Your example code:

```
let i = query::<i32>("i");
```

Is specifying the type **twice** — once as the type parameter `<i32>`, and once as the string `"i"`. This is quite odd, so my guess is that really the argument is a name of a key-value pair. This makes me think of how the Rust [Postgres crate](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres) works (pseudocode shown):

```
let id: i32 = row.get(0);
let name: String = row.get(1);
```

I'd believe that you can piggyback on `FromStr` and add some boilerplate:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::str::FromStr;

struct ConfigFile {
    raw: HashMap<String, String>,
}

impl ConfigFile {
    fn read_from_disk() -> Self {
        let mut map = HashMap::new();
        map.insert("name".into(), "Anna".into());
        map.insert("points".into(), "210".into());
        map.insert("debugging".into(), "true".into());
        ConfigFile { raw: map }
    }

    fn get<T>(&self, name: &str) -> Option<T>
        where T: FromStr
    {
        self.raw.get(name).and_then(|v| v.parse().ok())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let conf = ConfigFile::read_from_disk();
    let n: String = conf.get("name").unwrap();
    let p: i32    = conf.get("points").unwrap();
    let d: bool   = conf.get("debugging").unwrap();
    println!("{} has {} points, {}", n, p, d);
}
```